# How to disable the 'save image as' popup for smartphones for <input>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smartphone

On a webpage I made I use the `input` tag with as source an image.
When the button is pressed too long on smartphones there is a popup window with "save as" etc.

I searched for options to stop this from happening as buttons need to be kept pressed down by the user because it's a kind of game.

I already put these commands in the CSS tag on input but there still appear popups:

```
-webkit-touch-callout:none; 
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select:none;
```

I can't use `pointer-events:none;` as it disables clicking on the button on computer

please let me know if you know how to fix this, I had the same problem when I used an  tag

(ps, I let the button work by linking it to JavaScript with the `$('#ID').mousedown`, `up` and `leave` commands)

Here is an image of the popup I'm trying to avoid incase you don't know what I'm talking about

[image: example]

As requested, here is the way I use the input tag, the img tag also gave the same problem work when I used it the same way

```
html:
<input type="image" src="up.png"     class="UpKeyImage" id="Up">

javascript (with jquery):
$('#Up').mousedown(function() {$("#Dancer").attr("src","dancerup.png");});
$('#Up').mouseup(function() {$("#Dancer").attr("src","dancer.png");});
$('#Up').mouseleave(function() {$("#Dancer").attr("src","dancer.png");});
```

Comment: "*On a webpage I made I use the input tag with as source an image*" can you show this implementation here? Maybe the easiest workaround will be to change this.

Comment: @NicoO I added the code I used, I want to keep an image changed for as long as the button is pushed down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not test it, but this would be worth a try.

I  assume that `<input type="image" />` is beeing treaded like an `<img>` by your browser.

To prevent this, you can change your input type to `type="submit"` or `type="button"` which should not show the image context menu. For this to work you will have to alter your html and your css. This is not really more correct than your solution, but it should help you at your problem:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" class="UpKeyImage" id="Up" value="Up" />
```

New CSS:

```
.UpKeyImage {
    /*this will hide the value*/
    text-indent: -999em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    /*Downside of this solution, you will need to define the width and height*/
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    /*this will be dancerup.png*/
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.UpKeyImage.dance-up {
    /* path to the other image */
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/sports/400/200/);
}
```

And some new jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#Up')
    .mouseup(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("dance-up");
    })
    .mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("dance-up");
    })
    .mousedown(function () {
        $(this).addClass("dance-up");
    });
});
```

**Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nr9ffw84/**

Comment: Thank you, I now just finished implementing it. It's less convenient than how I did it before but it works so that's great.

What is the advantage/difference with the method of changing the picture compared to the one I used tho? does it not do more or less the same?

Comment: @Pineapple thats a good question. There are no real advantages to your method. Since the context menu you had a Problem with, is an image context menu, i assumed that the Input Type image is handeled like an image. With the method in my answer there is no context for the browser to show this menu. Glad it worked

Comment: Would your method be better for quick response time or not? I already tried preloading images that get used as src by doing

    [var dancerz= new Image();
    dancerz.src = "dancerz.png"] (in javascript)

For each different src but I don't know if changing the src of an image makes i load (and download from server?) again or use the loaded one.

Comment: When you load the css file with the Images in the Header of your document you could have a tiny Performance bump. But not really worth a mention. You should be looking at Sprites for seamless image swap

Comment: Wow, I was not aware of that! I'm going to try and use this. the images are the same size so it should work with that. thanks a lot mate, you helped me very much!

Answer (score 0):

Another easy work around is that:
Add a  or a  as the parent to receive the mouse click events, 
then set the  css as: pointer-events: none;

Answer (score -3):

why don't you use 'pointer-events:none' inside of a media container so it only applies to smartphones?

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    input {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: `I can't use pointer-events:none; as it disables clicking on the button on computer`

Comment: I tested it and using pointer-events: none; also disables the buttons for smartphones

Comment: @Moogs clearly the media container means it would not disable clicking the button on a computer. Sorry I couldn't help.