# HTML5 game how to disable context menu when long click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to adapt this same method from this stackoverflow:
[How to disable the 'save image as' popup for smartphones for <input>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668612/how-to-disable-the-save-image-as-popup-for-smartphones-for-input)

I'm facing an issue where my button doesn't show at all.

My HTML Button

```
  <div id="right" style="margin-right: 50px;" class="socialNetworkNav">
                <!-- Add a Anchor tag with nested img tag here -->
                <input type="image" src="images/UXwr4.png">
            </div>
```

I've Javascript function for `onclick` and `longpress` . 
I'm figuring how to tackle the longpress so it doesn't show the context menu to save the image.

I've also tried this way yet no luck, the context menu still appears
Html:

`input type="button" class="buttonimg" >`

CSS:

```
   .buttonimg{
background-img : url (....png);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to contextmenu event and return false.

To track long press you can check time difference between `mousedown` and `contextmenu` event;

see working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/aoejL2jq/)

Comment: I tried contenxtmenu return false, but when on mobile. I can't even trigger the button nor the onclick

Comment: are you saying that when you return false on contextmenu on mobile it doesn't click? I don't think mobile browsers can understand that event at all, probably there's something else.

Comment: yeap, i'm trying to figure out how to not foil the function of the onclick. It's pretty weird. But on web browser it will work .